# Get all channels a user has read/write permissions in a guild discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to write a function which can take in a discord user ID and return a list of channels they have send/read messages (either or, doesn't matter) permissions to.

I can't figure it out and am not even sure if it's possible. Everything I've seen online checks what roles have permissions or what users have roles etc, but I need to just get a list of channels where the user has those permissions.

I also don't need to use the discord.js library, the plain discord API would work too.

Here is the code I've tried

```
Client.once('ready', async () => {
  const guild = await Client.guilds.fetch(GUILD_ID);
  const channel = await guild.channels.fetch(USER_NO_ACCESS_CHANNEL_ID);
  if (!channel || !channel.isTextBased() || !(channel instanceof TextChannel)) {
    throw new Error("No channel found");
  }
  const member = await guild.members.fetch(STEEL_USER_ID);
  console.log(channel.permissionsFor(member).has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages));
  // Logs `true` even when the member has no access to the given channel
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
const guild = null; // Replace with whatever guild object you want.
const member = null; // Replace with whatever member object you want.
let channels = guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type == ChannelType.GuildText);



channels = channels.filter((channel) => {
  if (channel.permissionsFor(member).has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel)) return true;
  return false;
})
```

The above snippet will get a collection of the guild's channels cache, it will then filter through it all and only return the entries (channels) that the member can view.

You can then use that collection however you like as well as loop through it using .forEach.